# Failed to store data in laravel 8

Tags: mysql, laravel, web, eloquent, laravel-8

I'm making a form so that users can request to create a new account to the admin, but every time I try to send data, it always fails, even though I've checked every part of my code, can anyone help me?

the form code :

```
                                            <form method="POST" action="{{ url('/request-akun/make-request') }}">
                                                @csrf
                                                <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                                    <label for="name">Nama</label>
                                                    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name">
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                                                    <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" id="email">
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                                                    <input type="text" name="password" class="form-control"
                                                        id="password">
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                                    <label for="password_confirm">Konfirmasi Password</label>
                                                    <input name="password_confirm" type="text" class="form-control"
                                                        id="password">
                                                </div>
                                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right"
                                                    style="margin-right: 15px;">Request</button>
                                            </form>
```

this is the controller :

```
public function requestAccount(Request $request){
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'ra_instansi_id' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255',
            'password' => 'required',
            'password_confirm' => 'required'
        ]);
        if ($request->get('password') == $request->get('password_confirm')){
            $data = new requestAkun();
            $data->name = $request->get('name');
            $data->ra_user_id = Auth::id();
            $data->ra_instansi_id = Auth::user()->instansiID;
            $data->email = $request->get('email');
            $data->password = $request->get('password');
            $data->status = "pending";
            $data->save();
            return Redirect::to('/request-akun/request-lists')->with('success','Request Berhasil dikirim');
        } else {
            return Redirect::to('/request-akun/request-lists')->with('error','Password tidak sama');
        }  
    }
```

this is the model code:

```
class requestAkun extends Model
{
    use HasFactory, Uuids;
    protected $table = 'request_akun';
    public $timestamps = true;
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'ra_instansi_id',
        'ra_user_id',
        'email',
        'password',
        'status'
    ];
}
```

this is the route :

```
Route::prefix('request-akun')->group(function(){
        Route::post('/make-request',[userController::class,'requestAccount'])->name('make-request');
    });
```

Comment: you are passing data with `POST` method , so replace `$request->get('password')` by `$request->password`

Answer (score 0):

1. Error is you don't have `ra_instansi_id` input in your form.
2. Not showing any validation error message in your form so better show errors so you check which validation failed.

3.Instead of checking password match in if condition you can change input name `password_confirm` to `password_confirmation` so you can change like below

```
<input name="password_confirmation" type="text" class="form-control"
                                   id="password_confirmation">
```

and in your validation

```
 $validator=Validator::make($request->all(),[
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'ra_instansi_id' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed',
            'password_confirmation' => 'required'
        ]);

dd($validator->errors());
```